# Ampscript in radio button

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

I want help in AMP script for below scenario:
I am using this radio button but in my Data Extension the data is not going, although the data of other fields are going except this radio button.
This is the html:

```
<div class="radio-box form-group">
                        <label>Preferred method of contact</label>
                        <div class="radio-box-inner">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group" name="preferredContact"> 
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadio11"  class="custom-control-input" name="preferredContact">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" name="preferredContact" for="customRadio11">Phone</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group" name="preferredContact">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadio12"  class="custom-control-input" name="preferredContact">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" name="preferredContact" for="customRadio12">Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio" name="preferredContact">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadio13"  class="custom-control-input" name="preferredContact">
                                <label class="custom-control-label" name="preferredContact" for="customRadio13">Whatsapp</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and this is the Ampscript:

```
%%[
IF RequestParameter("submitted")==true THEN

Var  @insert , @FutureCommunication , @FirstName , @email, @LastName, @phone, @Occupation , @productInfo , @Categories , @RequestInfo, @preferredContact 

SET @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
SET @email = RequestParameter("email")
SET @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
SET @phone = RequestParameter("phone")
SET @Occupation = RequestParameter("Occupation")
SET @productInfo = RequestParameter("productInfo")
SET @Categories = RequestParameter("Categories")
SET @RequestInfo = RequestParameter("RequestInfo")  
SET @preferredContact = RequestParameter("preferredContact")

IF (RequestParameter("FutureCommunication") == "communication") THEN

SET @FutureCommunication = "Yes"

ELSE

SET @FutureCommunication = "No"

ENDIF

SET @insert = UpsertData('Test DE 1',3,'FirstName',@FirstName, 'email',@email, 'LastName',@LastName, 'phone',@phone, 'Occupation ',@Occupation, 'Categories ',@Categories, 'RequestInfo ',@RequestInfo,'preferredContact ',@preferredContact)

endif
]%%
%%[ ELSE ]%%
```

Comment: it appears you are missing a value for the radio button https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: @EazyE Thank you It helped a lot